# Can three individual solutions of StreamPlot be shown separately?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have the given code

```
b = 3.3925 // Rationalize;
k = 2.95 // Rationalize;
n = 157759;
R=1.05;
F[s_, i_, R_, k_] := {-k*R*i*s / n, k* (R* i* s / n - i)}; 
pl1 = StreamPlot[F[s, i, R,k], {s, 0, n}, {i, 0, n}, AxesLabel->{"s","i"}]
```

and I want to show the individual solution for case 1: n=157, case 2: n=1000, and n=5000.

How can this be done, since this shows a whole vector field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With[
    {
        b = 3.3925 // Rationalize,
        k = 2.95 // Rationalize,
        r = 1.05
    },
    Row@Table[
        StreamPlot[
            F[s, i, r, k]
            , {s, 0, n}
            , {i, 0, n}
            , FrameLabel-> {"s","i"}
            , PlotLabel -> StringTemplate["Case n= ``"][n]
            , ImageSize -> 300
        ]
        ,{n,{157,1000,5000}}
    ]
]
```

[image]